# PyQT5 - Is it impossible to nest widgets within new widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have frames designed in seperate scripts that are all called to this central gui script which shows them using QMainWindow as one would expect.

However, I am trying to redesign the Main Window in such a way that there is a permanently fixed frame on the right hand side, and a tabbed frame on the left.

Before I attempted to make this happen, I could display, using setlayout, all of the frames on the mainwindow at once, however, when I try to add several of these"sub-widget" frames to my new tabbed frame everything gets annoying...

... effectively, I am taking already functioning widgets (designed w/ QFrame) called from other scripts and trying to make 2 new widgets with them (QTabWidget, for the left frame, and QGroupBox for the right). However, when run, the window pops up with my groupbox and tabwidgets completely empty, and my "sub-widgets" are displayed in new windows.

Here is a snippet:

```
    tab_frame = QWidget()
    tab_frame.layout = QVBoxLayout() #-------------------- Layout
    tab_frame.layout.addWidget(self.FRAME_FROM_OTHER_SCRIPT)
    tab_frame.layout.addStretch(1)
    
    #### Tabs Parent ####
    tabs = QTabWidget()
    tabs.layout = QVBoxLayout()
    tabs.addTab(tab_frame,"Tab 1")
    
    #### Fixed Frame ####
    vbox_az = QGroupBox()
    vbox_az.layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout() #------------------------ Layout
    vbox_az.layout.addWidget(self.FRAME_FROM_OTHER_SCRIPT)


    self.main_grid = QGridLayout() #--------------------------- Layout
    self.main_grid.addWidget(tabs,0,0,1,2)
    self.main_grid.addWidget(vbox_az,0,2,1,3)

    self.main_grid.setColumnStretch(2,1)
    self.main_grid.setColumnStretch(5,1)
    
    self.main_window.setLayout(self.main_grid)
```

I am unsure of what is actually happening... are widgets unable to be nested within other widgets?

Because setLayout relies on a layout input and not a widget I am unsure of how else to attack this problem other than by grouping my "sub-widgets" into groupboxes but I do not know why it's going so wrong.

Here is a picture screen-grab to illustrate further:
(for the sake of my question I have asked to split my window into two portions though I am actually splitting it three times)
[image]

Comment: You're just adding widgets to layouts, but you're *not* setting the layouts. Creating a `layout` attribute is not sufficient to set that layout (and you should also *not* overwrite `layout`). Use `tab_frame.layout = QVBoxLayout(tab_frame)` or `tab_frame.setLayout(tab_frame.layout)`, and the same for the other layouts. Also, if `self.main_window` is a QMainWindow, you cannot use `setLayout()`, since QMainWindow has its own *private* layout which cannot be overridden, you can only set a layout on the *central widget*. If you want more help, please [edit] your post and provide a [mre].

Comment: This fixed up the issue. Thank you SOOO much. I am learning as I go so I appreciate your help immeasurably.